# Using PCA to select best variables, and then performing Linear Regression?

Tags: pca, linear-model, feature-selection, model

I am currently working on variable selection and came accross many methods which i tested.

I tried one which i thought of, but never read about it. I would be curious if you know anything about it:

What is commonly used is PCR: You use the projections of the individuals on the new dimensions which were calculated from a PCA. This does not select any variable, but mostly take in account the variables which contribute the most to each axis.

However, since i wanted to select variables, i tried to take the variable contributing the most to each axis of a PCA and then building a linear model out of it.
I tried it, and the results are really good for my data: It outperformed Lasso, RF, BestSubset... I think it is because i'm trying to model field data which describe the same reality as the descriptive variables i'm using (teledetection).

I wanted to know if this method already exist anywhere, in order to read about it (as i highly doubt i've invented anything) and assess it's flaws.

Comment: This sounds like an *ad hoc* factor analysis.  Provided you have validated the results (by withholding a test set or through cross-validation, for instance) then it's perfectly fine.  But one reason you might see better "performance" is that you could be overfitting the data.

Comment: what do you mean by ad hoc factor analysis ?

Comment: It means a procedure mathematically akin to factor analysis but without any theoretical principle to justify it.

Comment: considerign the fact that Factor analysis can maximize various things including variance of the point cloud, like PCA, then i should get the same result performing FA or PCA.
Isn'it  right ?

Thanks a lot for your answer as it gave me quite a lot of guidance.